# r.js optmiser: $ not defined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm trying to use the r.js optimiser for the first time.
My main file looks like this:

```
/*--- Require.js: the main module loader ---*/
require.config({

    baseUrl: 'assets/js', 
    waitSeconds: 0,    
    paths   : { 
        jquery                  : '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min', 
        jqueryui                : '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min', 
        underscore              : 'vendor/underscore/underscore-min', 
        backbone                : 'vendor/backbone/backbone', 
        routefilter             : 'vendor/backbone.routefilter/backbone.routefilter', 
        marionette              : 'vendor/marionette/marionette', 
        tpl                     : 'vendor/require/tpl', 
        async                   : 'vendor/async/async', 
        require_async           : 'vendor/require/require_async', 
        modernizr               : 'vendor/modernizr/modernizr.custom.15872', 
        hello                   : 'vendor/hello/hello', 
        facebook                : 'vendor/hello/facebook', 
        google                  : 'vendor/hello/google', 
        moment                  : 'vendor/moment/moment', 
        $dropdown               : 'vendor/jquery.dropdown/jquery.dropdown', 
        spin                    : 'vendor/spin/spin', 
        selectBoxIt             : 'vendor/selectBoxIt/selectBoxIt', 
        maskedinput             : 'vendor/maskedinput/maskedinput', 
        multidatespicker        : 'vendor/multidatespicker/jquery-ui.multidatespicker'
        //markerclusterer         : 'vendor/markerclusterer/markerclusterer'
    }, 

    shim    : {
        underscore: {
          exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: { 
            deps        : ['jquery', 'underscore'], 
            exports     : 'Backbone' 
        }, 
        marionette: {
            deps        : ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], 
            exports     : 'Marionette' 
        }, 
        routefilter: { 
            deps        : ['marionette', 'backbone', 'underscore', 'jquery'], 
            exports     : 'Routefilter' 
        }, 

        selectBoxIt: { 
            deps        : ['jquery', 'jqueryui'], 
            exports     : 'SelectBoxIt' 
        }, 

        multidatespicker: {
            deps        : ['jquery', 'jqueryui'], 
            exports     : 'MultidatesPicker' 
        }, 

        facebook: {
            deps        : ['hello'], 
            exports     : 'Facebook' 
        }, 

        google: {
            deps        : ['hello'], 
            exports     : 'Google'
        } 
        //markerclusterer: { 
        //    exports     : 'Markerclusterer' 
        //}
    }, 
    config: {
        moment: {
            noGlobal: true
        }
    }
}); 

//--- Define Google maps to make it globally accessible throughout the application ---// 
define('gmaps', ['require_async!https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=geometry,places&key=AIzaSyDRKg-SNBODA1mKMCRrfMrls48x7owr9w8&sensor=true"'],
function(){
    // return the gmaps namespace for brevity
    return window.google.maps;
}); 

//--- Define moment --- 
require(["moment"], function (moment) { 
    moment().format(); 
}); 

// --- Initialize the application ---// 
require([ 
  'zwoop', 'backbone' 

], function(Zwoop, Backbone){ 

    Zwoop.start(); 

});
```

The build file contains the following settings:

```
mainConfigFile:"js/main.js", 
baseUrl : "js",
name: "main",
out: "dist/main.js",
removeCombined: true, 
findNestedDependencies: false, 
paths: {
    jquery: "empty:"
}
```

I don't receive any errors, but unfortunately I receive an error in the browser:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

It appears that either jquery is not properly loaded from the CDN, or that something is not working correctly regarding the shim.
Can you spot what the error might be?

Comment: Try removing all the jquery dependency in your `shim` properties

Comment: Why would I do that ..?

Comment: I remember having a similar problem and I can't recall exactly what I did, bit looking back at my config I noticed that all my jQuery deps are commented out

Comment: That's strange... I thought the shim was supposed to indicate the dependencies of the third party libraries I'm using on libraries such as jquery.

Comment: Yes, of course. And when an asset is initialized, its dependencies are initialized first. I'm wondering if there isn't a conflict between Require initializing jQuery or jQuery registering itself with Require

Comment: Another suggestion. Most new Backbone versions are AMD aware and don't need shims. Try taking the Backbone shim out.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out later this week when I find the time. Shims are no necessity when adapting the code, but the do exist so I guess that they serve a good purpose.

Comment: Shims are a very tell necessary, for libraries that are not AMD aware. Backbone knows how to register itself and take care of its own dependencies.